# How to exit the loop :while(cin>>n) in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

This is a program that counts how many letters and numbers a string has,but when I Press *Enter* to exit after entering,it has no response.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    int nums=0,chars=0;
    while(cin>>c){
        if(c>='0'&&c<='9'){
            nums++;
        }else if((c>='A'&&c<='Z')||(c>='a'&&c<='z')){
            chars++;
        }

    }
    printf("nums:%d\nchars:%d",nums,chars);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `std::isdigit`.

Comment: Enter/Return does not end input from `std::cin`, it just ends a line. Try using `std::getline` and walking across a `std::string`.

Comment: Try printing your char as an integer as the first line in loop.  You might notice something about where you might need to `break;`. Better way is to get line and ditch the while as jkb said...

Comment: `Ctrl+D` on Linux/Mac, and `Ctrl-Z` on Windows would send EOF and break the loop. If you redirect input from a file it will also exit when the end of the file is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing enter does not end input from `std::cin` and `std::cin` stops when encountering a whitespace.

Better would be to use `std::getline` and `std::isdigit` as shown below:

```
int main()
{
    
    int nums=0,chars=0;
    std::string input;
    //take input from user 
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    for(const char&c: input){
        if(std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))){
            
            nums++;
        }
        else if(std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))){
            chars++;
            
        }

    }
    std::cout<<"nums: "<<nums<<" chars: "<<chars;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/W0NKLEi0u9)

Comment: It looks like the OP is looking specifically for numbers and letters, so the `else` should probably be `else if (std::isalpha(c))`

Comment: @jkb Done, check out the updated answer.